# Android Convert RXJava 2 Maybe to a coroutine?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, coroutine

My project intends to replace RxJava with coroutines.

Use RxJava Maybe.concat to access network and database data.

First search for the data in the database, if there is no data in the database, download the data from the Internet.
If the database has data, the network data will not be downloaded.

**Is there a way for coroutine to achieve a similar function?**

**And, Is it necessary to use 'kotlinx-coroutines-rx2'?**

```
fun getMovieImg(): Flowable<MovieBean> {
    return Maybe.concat(
        CacheModelFactory.getMovieImgDisk().firstElement(), // database
        getMovieImgNetwork().firstElement() // net
    ).firstElement().toFlowable()
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: `Is there a way for coroutine to achieve a similar function?` well, why wouldn't it be possible :) you're really just describing an if statement -> `if there is no data in the database, download the data from the Internet. If the database has data, the network data will not be downloaded.`, this seems quite possible to achieve using `Flow`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with coroutines and because coroutines were invented specifically to allow regular, sequential programming even with IO, it is actually much easier than with RxJava. We don't need any maybes, streams, flows or whatever. We implement this the same way as for the regular, non-IO code:

```kotlin
suspend fun getMovieImg(): MovieBean = getMovieImgDisk() ?: getMovieImgNetwork()

suspend fun getMovieImgDisk(): MovieBean? { ... }
suspend fun getMovieImgNetwork(): MovieBean { ... }
```

Assuming you replace RxJava entirely in your application, you don't need `kotlinx-coroutines-rx2` for this. But if you only create a coroutine adapter on top of the existing code using RxJava, then you will probably need some utils that will help you to convert RxJava objects to coroutines/suspendable code.